# DeadLock example on Brute-Force attack

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, deadlock, brute-force

The simple project below implement brute-force algorithm by using java concurrency. This version of the code try to find the password that contain digits only ( 0-9 ) going through digits the algorithm automatically increment the number of digits in the string that could be potential password which needs to find.

**What I looking for**.
I would like to change the code in the way that it will be possible to get deadlock in order to understand what is wrong and what is right. Also, I would like to play with this deadlock in debugging mode. Moreover, it would be great if you show me the a solution of this deadlock. Please tell me what add to the code in order to receive deadlock and what the solution of this deadlock will be ? 
The code of **first brute-force project** below

```
package bfpasswrd_multi;


  import java.util.Scanner;

  public class Test

  {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    System.out.print("Type password to be cracked: ");
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    String input = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
    PasswordCracker cracker = new PasswordCracker();
    System.out.println("Multithreaded");
    cracker.runMulti(input);
    cracker = new PasswordCracker();


    System.out.println("Finished...");
    }
}
```

---

```
package bfpasswrd_multi;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;


public class PasswordCracker
{

String passwordToCrack;
public boolean passwordFound;
int min;
int max;
StringBuffer crackedPassword;

public void prepare(String text)
{
    passwordToCrack = text;

    passwordFound = false;
    min = 48;
    max = 57;                               // http://ascii.cl/
    crackedPassword = new StringBuffer();
    crackedPassword.append((char) (min - 1));           
}

public void result()
{
    System.out.println("Cracked Password is: " + crackedPassword.toString());
}

public void incrementString(StringBuffer toCrack, int min, int max)
{
    toCrack.setCharAt(0, (char) ((int) toCrack.charAt(0) + 1));
    for (int i = 0; i < toCrack.length(); i++)
    {
        if (toCrack.charAt(i) > (char) max)
        {
            toCrack.setCharAt(i, (char) min);
            if (toCrack.length() == i + 1)
            {
                toCrack.append((char) min);
            }
            else
            {
                toCrack.setCharAt(i + 1, (char) ((int) toCrack.charAt(i + 1) + 1));
            }
        }
    }
}

public void runMulti(String text)
{
    prepare(text);
    double time = System.nanoTime();
    doItMulti();
    time = System.nanoTime() - time;
    System.out.println(time / (1000000000));
    result();

}


public void doItMulti()
{
    int cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    ArrayList<Future<?>>(cores));
    List<Future<?>>  futures ;  
    futures =   Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Future<?>>(cores));     
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(cores);
    final long step = 2000;
    for (long i = 0; i < Long.MAX_VALUE; i += step)
    {
        while(futures.size() > cores)
        {
            for(int w = 0; w < futures.size();w++)
            {
                if(futures.get(w).isDone())
                {
                    futures.remove(w);
                    break;
                }
            }
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(0);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        {
            final long j = i;
            if (passwordFound == false)
            {
                futures.add(executor.submit(new Runnable()
                {

                    public void run()
                    {
                        long border = j + step;
                        StringBuffer toCrack = new StringBuffer(10);
                        toCrack.append(constructString3(j, min, max));
                        for (long k = j; k < border; k++)
                        {
                            incrementString(toCrack, min, max);
                            boolean found = toCrack.toString().equals(passwordToCrack);
                            if (found)
                            {
                                crackedPassword = toCrack;
                                passwordFound = found;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }));
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    executor.shutdownNow();
}

public String constructString3(long number, long min, long max)
{

    StringBuffer  text = new StringBuffer();        
    if (number > Long.MAX_VALUE - min)              
    {
        number = Long.MAX_VALUE - min;              
    }                                                

    ArrayList<Long> vector = new ArrayList<Long>(10);
    vector.add(min - 1 + number);
    long range = max - min + 1;
    boolean nextLetter = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++)
    {
        long nextLetterCounter = 0;
        while (vector.get(i) > max)
        {
            nextLetter = true;
            long multiplicator = Math.abs(vector.get(i) / range);
            if ((vector.get(i) - (multiplicator * range)) < min)
            {
                multiplicator -= 1;
            }
            vector.set(i, vector.get(i) - (multiplicator * range));
            nextLetterCounter += multiplicator;
        }
        if (nextLetter)
        {
            vector.add((long) (min + nextLetterCounter - 1));
            nextLetter = false;
        }
        text.append((char) vector.get(i).intValue());
    }
    return text.toString();
}
}
```

Many thanks in advance ! As you can see this brute-force example absent of any locks. Therefore, as far as I understand it will be difficult to make a deadlock on this code. However, I found another implementation of the brute-force execution which is obviously and unfortunately more complicated because it uses GUI and SHA-1. I haven't time to get rid of those complication, so forgive me in advance. But, as far as, I understand the second project will be more suitable for deadlock demonstration because it executes multi-threading not through ExecutionService interface but through the usage of locks and synchronization methods. Please take a look. ( the code below ) and if I mess up this some fundamental terms forgive me for my "ultimate noobidity" in given topic. I truly have very little places and time to advance my knowledge in the direction of java concurrency, but right now I need this knowledge as never before.

The code of **second brute-force project** below.

```
// *****************************************
    package pl.scriptease.studia.prir;

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;


public class BruteForce extends Thread {

    public static Object lock = new Object();
    public static GUI gui;
    static String sha1 = "";
    static int length = 1;
    static int numberOfThreads = 1;
    private static int nextThreadId = 1;
    static String textAreaBuffer = "";
    static String password = "";
    static ExecutorService executor;
    static Set<Thread> threadSet;
    volatile boolean running = false;
    boolean foundPassword = false;
    int threadId = 0;
    long startTime;
    long endTime;
    long elapsedTime;
    String start;
    String temporary;
    String end;
    static char[] searcharea = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyz".toCharArray();

    void loop() {
    temporary = start;

    while (running) {

        // print(this + " checking: " + temp);
        if (check(temporary)) {
        foundPassword = true;
        password = temporary;
        gui.passwordFound(password);
        print("password was found: '" + temporary + "'");
        this.interrupt();
        shutdown();
        break;
        }

        temporary = search(temporary);

        if (interrupted()) {
        break;
        }

        if (temporary.length() > length) {
        break;
        }

        if (temporary.length() >= length && temporary.startsWith(end) && end.charAt(0) != last()) {
        break;
        }
    }

    running = false;
    }

    public String search(String temp) {

    String sample = "";
    int length = temp.length();
    char[] a = temp.toCharArray();

    for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        if (i == 0) {
        if (a[i] == end.charAt(0)) {
            a[i] = start.charAt(0);
            sample = new String(a) + first();
            break;
        }
        }

        a[i] = next(a[i]);  // next character to match with original password 

        if (a[i] != first()) {
        sample = new String(a);
        break;
        } else {
        if (i == 0) {
            sample = new String(a) + first();
        }
        }
    }

    return sample;
    }

    private static char next(char ch) {
    if (ch == searcharea[searcharea.length - 1]) {
        return searcharea[0];
    } else {
        return searcharea[indexOf(ch) + 1];
    }
    }

    static boolean check(String s) {
    return toSha1(s).equals(sha1);
    }   // compare SHA codes 

    static char first() {
    return searcharea[0];
    }

    static char last() {
    return searcharea[searcharea.length - 1];
    }

    static int indexOf(char c) {
    for (int i = 0; i < searcharea.length; ++i) {
        if (searcharea[i] == c) {
        return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
    }

    BruteForce(String start, String end) {
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
    threadId = nextThreadId;
    ++nextThreadId;
    }   // Gives Id to the threads that we later will see on the log window 

    public void run() {
    print("started on interval [" + start + ", " + end + "]");
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    running = true;
    loop();
    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;
    print(String.format("ended with time:  %.2f sec", elapsedTime / 1e3));
    }

    public String toString() {
    return "[T" + threadId + "]";   
    }   // return name of the thread that do the job in the log window

    public static String toSha1(String input) {
    try {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        return byteArrayToHexString(md.digest(input.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    } // convert password that you write down to the SHA code 
    catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
    }

    private static String byteArrayToHexString(byte[] b) {
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        result += Integer.toString((b[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1);
    }
    return result;
    }

    public static void decrypt() {

    threadSet = new HashSet<Thread>();

    int searchAreaLength = searcharea.length;
    int interval = (int) Math.round(searchAreaLength / numberOfThreads);    // the works divided between thread equally 

    executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);
//  executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; ++i) {

        int start = i * interval;
        int end = (i + 1) * interval;

        if (end >= searchAreaLength) {
        end = searchAreaLength - 1;
        }

        Thread worker = new BruteForce(searcharea[start] + "", searcharea[end] + "");
        executor.execute(worker);
        threadSet.add(worker);
    }
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
    try {
        executor.shutdown();
        nextThreadId = 1;
        sleep(500);
        executor.shutdownNow();

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
    }

    private void print(String text) {
    String time = String.format("%tT: ", Calendar.getInstance());
    synchronized (lock) {
        textAreaBuffer += (time + this + " : " + text + "\n");
    }
    }

    public static String pullTextAreaBuffer() {
    synchronized (lock) {
        String ret = textAreaBuffer;
        textAreaBuffer = "";
        return ret;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the stackoverflow didn't allow me to enter GUI ( and main function ) for the second brute-force project ( more than 30k characters ) . If somebody ask me to post it , I'll make it with love to.

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like you didn't allow yourself to spend some time on the help center in order to understand what kind of questions you can ask here. There is not much chance that people will read through a lot of complicated, badly formatted, not-very-clean code ...  in order to tell you how to rework your code to run into certain kind of problems. Sorry, but this doesn't belong here.

Comment: Thx you for your reply and attention. Besides spending time in help center, what is your piece of advice will be so far at least add comments ? Am I right ?

Comment: I would a suggest to read about "clean code", SOLID OO design (using static all over the place: ugly ugly ugly) to learn how to write better code; and in case you want to learn about multi-threading and locks and so on: then look out for tutorials that give you good examples; instead of taking **some sort of code that does something** and trying to "push" that code into "failing". In other words: multi-threading and locking is by itself **complex**; do you really think it helps "learning" when you wrap that topic into such a complicated "example" as pw-cracking?

Comment: If shortly I don't know. As for me now, java concurrency is tangled ball of yarn and I'm just looking around how disentangle it and to put all terms on the shelves. In my humble opinion, it would be much worse if I did not do the posts, would not hear your critique and in isolation be boiled in my own noobs thoughts. Right now, I'm glad that you told me what you think, I much appreciate it.

Comment: I understand: but as said; SO is not a place to learn about new things by "discussing" them there. Instead --- step 1: read about the concepts. step 2: find a good tutorial and start coding. step 3: extend those examples, adding your own ideas. step 4: now, if you run into "real" problems during step2/3 ... write up questions here.

Comment: Thank for your pieces of advice. This is really important for me ! Now I blame myself that I shy and didn't ask questions before. I think I'll take your idea further. First of all, I'll make some research then I'll make a SO post with hit parade of the best sources for "java concurrency first steps". In order to don't waste time on shiny but unreliable video tutorials and books. Once again, thx you so much :)

Comment: Probably not a good idea - the help center tells you that questions like "what are the best resources for xyz" ... do not fit here, either ;-(

Comment: Okey, got it. I figure this problem out. thx a lot ! :)